# Filtering Data By Full Name React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, filter

Hi I am Trying to filter my Data By Full Name, my API takes in a first and last name and I am returning it as:

```
const filteredStudents = students.filter( student => {
    return (student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) + student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
})
```

which only shows a result when typing a first or last name is there a way to handle a condition for when you type in the whole name?

For Example, "Bill Gates"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the names first, then check if the search term is contained.

```
const filteredStudents = students.filter((student) => {
  return `${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}`
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(search.toLowerCase());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Drew, This works as my previous return statement if they are joined together. Is there a way to take into mind the space in between first and last name?

Comment: @Debug Yes, just add a space in the templated string.